# Dynamic variable in PHP [GET]

Tags: php, get, include

I'm trying to use the php get. everthing is working find exept the include page.
it's adding 1 at the end of include content
any ide how do i ride that?

example:

```
I love norway
I love norway1
```

Code:

```
<?php
if($_GET['boy'] == 'zabi') $zabkas =  'it is Zabi';
if($_GET['girl'] == 'veronka') $verona = 'It is veronka';
if($_GET['place'] == 'norway') $norge = include('norway.php');
?>

<?php echo $zabkas ?>
<?php echo $verona ?>
<?php echo $norge ?>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not a link to an image of the code (have you never heard of copy/paste?).... and what i the content of your included file as well? Are you echoing the message there and then echoing the result of including the file? You are aware that include returns a true/1 if successful?

Comment: I've never used this site to ask people. it did not allowed me to paste my code.
Anyway here is my code: 

[http://codepad.org/enxwr3LS](http://codepad.org/enxwr3LS)

Comment: The site will not block you from posting your code; the editor even has a special code button, the `{}` button

Comment: All right, did u get my point on that error?

Comment: I guess you have echo "I love you norway"; in norway.php, it does't work like the way you think. You can do return "I love..." in norway.php. But yeah - next time include your code, as text, here. All of it, like this time 'norway.php' is the key file

Comment: No, i have only: i love norway in norway.php
the result is cooming is i love norway1

Comment: I'll repeat what I said in my previous comments.... your include file echoes 'I love you norway'.... but you assign the result of the include (a boolean true) to $norge, and then echo $norge (which echoes as a 1)

Answer (score 1):

Use the output buffer functions to capture the output from the included script.

```
<?php
if($_GET['boy'] == 'zabi') $zabkas =  'it is Zabi';
if($_GET['girl'] == 'veronka') $verona = 'It is veronka';
if($_GET['place'] == 'norway') {
    ob_start();
    include("norway.php");
    $norge = ob_get_clean();
}
?>

<?php echo $zabkas ?>
<?php echo $verona ?>
<?php echo $norge ?>
```

Comment: i though my problem were solved but, as i can see its including directly the norway.php not by GET

Comment: `GET` is only used when you access a URL on a webserver, not a local file.

Comment: It's not a local file, i do have it on my website.

Comment: Since the script is also on the website, it's a local file from there.

Comment: Also, if you try to access a PHP script remotely, the script is executed and the output is returned. That's not usually what you want with `include()`, which is to return the source so that it can be executed in the context of the original script.

Comment: i don't know what's the best solution for that, cuz i wanted to write more so i was thinking to do not destroy the code so i can include it the page. 

The page actualy contents only a simpe text

Comment: Use the `file_get_contents()` solution in the other answer.

Comment: i did, not any respons.

Comment: I don't have your codes, I can't copy an image into my file.

Comment: @Zabkas http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/zabkas.php?place=norway uses the `ob_start()` method

Comment: Why are you still doing `$norge = include('norway.php')`? My answer shows the correct way to do it.

Comment: try this, 

http://example.com/project/test.php?boy=zabi&girl=veronka&place=norway

Comment: I get **This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.** I don't understand how I'm supposed to use that.

Comment: Do you mean I should do `include('http://example.com/project/test.php?boy=zabi&girl=veronka&place=norway')`?

Answer (score 1):

We should use `file_get_contents`, instead of `include`.

```
$norge = file_get_contents("norway.php");
```

Comment: I'm really really sorry !!! u r correct !  i did something else wrong here ;) thx

Comment: @Barman  

Hi, i have an sms api there i'm sending a single sms. 
i was wondering if there is some codes that i can use for multiplate sms?

http://www.example.com/api/sendSms.php?apiKey=API_KEY&charset=UTF-8&senderId=47xxxxxxxx&mobile=47xxxxxxxx&message=How are u?